# How to Integrate the React-Native project to Android-Studio?

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I had tried to import the react-native project to android studio,
but the "index.android.js" file is not shown in android-studio IDE..
So what I will do ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to import "android" folder only.

Comment: yes i had import android folder only. but index.android.js file is not shown in IDE. @santosh

Comment: It will not show index.android.js. It is on root folder

Comment: but i want to edit the index.android.js file from IDE. can i do ? Because currently i am edit the index.android.js file in Sublime Text editor.

Comment: Then you need to go to File and open existing file (index.android.js) from Android Studio

Comment: See, index.android.js is a java script file then why are you not using JS editor like Atom and Sublime to edit js file?

Comment: Is the correct answer OP was probably looking for, that the idea is to write all the JavaScript files outside of Android studio? I get that you are suggesting that.. or it seems at least. I haven't tried it at all yet, but my assumption was as I'm assuming OPs is (that javascript can be managed in Android Studio too). Can you clarify for the unitiated?

Comment: I could see imported node modules, but I can not see Package.json because it is outside the root.

Answer (score 13):

To be able to see the root project files, you need to change your View Mode from "Android" (which is for native Android development only) to "Project", which is the mode for a generic project type and all the files will be in the same exact position as they will if you access them via folders

Screenshot for semplicity:

[image]

Comment: Can you work with react native inside Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, Logic: If you can do that in Sublime then why not in Android Studio! You can issue commands from terminal and import js files from root into Studio and edit there. IntelliJ IDE has support for .js files as well.

Answer (score 12):

When you create a React Native project, there is an android folder created by default. You should open Android Studio and go to File menu, then click open and then choose this file:

React Native project Root folder -> android -> app -> build.gradle

Then you should see project setup processes and finally project will open.

Comment: the React native project is also open in IDE by File->New->Import Project also. but i want the index.android.js file in IDE. and i want to editt this file from IDE only.. @Akhi Thank you.

Comment: You can drag drop this file into Android Studio as tab. Permission would be required to edit the .js files though.

Comment: But also I would like to see the root folder in Android project as I see other modules, and no file position from the root should be changed for this. But this should be for browsing purpose only. It should not be included as a folder to be compiled as source folder.